# service doing a periodic job

Tags: android, android-service

I am developing an Android app which must perform 2 periodic tasks in background:

1. download files from server every 24 hours.
2. perform file operations each week on phone sd card.

How do i do this?

Answer (score 3):

Firstly you need to use **AlarmManager**. When the registered alarm e.g. 24 hours case, will trigger, you can call service from the broadcast receiver of AlarmManager. You need to study a bit about AlarmManager if you don't already know. For further help you can get some idea from code below:

```
Calendar cur_cal = new GregorianCalendar();
cur_cal.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
Calendar cal = new GregorianCalendar();
cal.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR) + 1); //+1 For Next day (24 hours or so...)
cal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY,  hour);
cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE, minute);
cal.set(Calendar.SECOND, cur_cal.get(Calendar.SECOND));
cal.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, cur_cal.get(Calendar.MILLISECOND));
cal.set(Calendar.DATE, cur_cal.get(Calendar.DATE));
cal.set(Calendar.MONTH, cur_cal.get(Calendar.MONTH));

AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager)getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), AlarmReceiver.class);
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getApplicationContext(), 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);
am.cancel(pendingIntent);
am.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, cal.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent);
```

Here is how you can set your Alarm. Now when Alarm will be triggered, you will call your service like this:

```
public class AlarmReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver
{   
   @Override
   public void onReceive(Context arg0, Intent arg1)
   {    
           // Call you service or any task here
   }
}
```

Last thing, don't forget to mention your broadcast receiver and service in AndroidManifest.xml

```
<receiver android:name=".AlarmReceiver">
</receiver>    
<service android:name=".MyService"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's what official android docs says about [AlarmManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html)

```
Note: The Alarm Manager is intended for cases where you want to have 
your application code run at a specific time, even if your application 
is not currently running. For normal timing operations (ticks, timeouts, etc) 
it is easier and much more efficient to use Handler.
```

[Handler](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html) documentation.